# Approximating $\sqrt{3}$ via Newton's binomial theorem

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to use Newton's generalization of the Binomial Theorem:
$$(a+b)^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{i}a^ib^{m-i}$$
To approximate square roots by taking $x=\frac{1}{2}$

I've been using **R** for that matter. $\sqrt{2}$ worked perfectly, by doing $a=b=1$. You end up with $\sqrt{2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{i}$, which in **R** is computed as follows:

```
for (i in 0:100) {j<-j+choose(0.5,i)}
```

Which yields $j=1.414073$ when summing the first 100 terms.

Now, for $\sqrt{3}$, I can take $a=2$, $b=1$, and end up with $\sqrt{3}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{i}2^i$, which in **R** is computed as follows:

```
for (i in 0:100) {j<-j+choose(0.5,i)*2^i}
```

Which yields some ridiculously huge numbers. I believe the way I computed it is correct, so I figured it must be a mathematical error, so that's why I'm asking it here. Can you see my mistake here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can use $\binom{x}{i}$ with $x$ non-integer?

Comment: This won't converge everywhere. It only converges as long as $0<a+b<2$.

Comment: Yeah @the_candyman, that's the generalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: I know that. I was wondering if the choose function use the generalization or it is simply undefined for non-integer number

Comment: Oh, you mean, in **R**? If so, it sure does, I tried computing it without multiplying by $2^i$ and it does yield the actual values of the generalized choose function (plus it did work for the square root of 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac14}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^n{1/2\choose n}\frac1{4^n},
$$
hence
$$
\sqrt3=2-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac2{2n-1}{2n\choose n}\frac1{16^n}=2-\frac14-\frac1{64}-\frac7{1024}-\ldots
$$
The $n$th term is equivalent to
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}\cdot n\cdot4^n},
$$
hence keeping $n$ terms in the series above yields an error equivalent to
$$
\frac1{3\cdot\sqrt{\pi n}\cdot n\cdot4^n}.
$$
In particular, keeping $5k$ terms yields at least $3k$ accurate digits.

Likewise, $7^2=49=3\cdot4^2+1$ and $4\cdot49=196$ hence
$$
\sqrt3=\frac74-\frac74\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2n-1}{2n\choose n}\frac1{196^n},
$$
which adds (a little more than) $2$ accurate digits at each new term.

The next expansion in the same vein uses $97^2=9409=3\cdot56^2+1$ and $4\cdot9409=37636$ hence
$$
\sqrt3=\frac{97}{56}-\frac{97}{56}\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{2n-1}{2n\choose n}\frac1{37636^n}.
$$

Comment: Wow that converges really quickly, although I can't really see how to can get the second expression from the first one. Since the first one is $\sqrt{3}/2$, you can separate the first term and ass the others so nothing changes, and then multiply by 2 to get the aproximation of $\sqrt{3}$. But I don't know how $2\cdot\sum_{n\geq1}\binom{1/2}{n}\frac{1}{4^i}(-1)^i=\sum_{n\geq1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{2}{2n-1}\frac{1}{16^i}$, and moreover, why the latter expression does compute properly while the first one, doesn't, just like mine on the main post :S This is a mess!

Comment: ${2n\choose n}=(-1)^{n+1}4^n(2n-1){1/2\choose n}$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Did :D. After some more analyse, the first expression in your answer does compute properly as well. Thank god, it was starting to get frustrating. I'm really grateful, you put a lot of effort into the answer, and I'll definitely examine it more carefully to get the most out of it. I have another little question: ¿Why didn't my first approach on the main post work? Why does it work to get $\sqrt{3}/2$ first and then multiply by 2, but not doing it directly as in my main post?

Comment: The expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ diverges for $|x|\gt1$ and you use it for $x=2$...

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the clarification Did ;)